# conditional class not detected on mvn clean package

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have the following conditional class that should be unseen unless some other class annotates itself with a custom annotation:

```
@ConditionalOnBean(MyConf.class)
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CondClass{

   public void method() throws MessagingException
```

Then I have a spring boot test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public void myTest{
```

It works fine if I manually execute it, but if I do:

```
mvn clean package
```

I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class 
[it.bmed.medmad.arch.common.websocket.service.impl.CondClass] from ClassLoader 
 [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/messaging/MessagingException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException
```

Indeed that MessagingException is on a dependency that is not included, but I would expect that the whole class is not inspected because of the annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `@ConditionalOnClass(MyConf.class)`, too:

```java
@ConditionalOnClass(MyConf.class)
@ConditionalOnBean(MyConf.class)
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CondClass {
    // ...
}
```

sample: [official usage](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.java#L65)

Comment: To know `MyConf` is  "bean" or not, it needs to be loaded (but in this case, it is not exist on classpath).